# VBA Code wont execute but others in sheet run ok

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to google and this community I have learned a lot over past month or so and am getting more self sufficient with VBA but this is baffling me..

I have what I think is fairly straightforward code but it just won't run... I have tried debug with run to cursor and nothing happens - other VBA macros in the sheet work ok...

I also to out all the lines where I was setting the formuales incase there was some thing them causing issue but still doesn't execute...

```
Option Explicit
        Sub Start_Validation()
        Dim WSfrom As Worksheet
        Dim WS As Worksheet
        Dim Tbl As ListObject
        Set WS = Sheets("Validation Form")
        Set WSfrom = Sheets("DATA - Product Validation")
        Set Tbl = WSfrom.ListObjects("ProductTable")
        WS.Range("d18") = WSfrom.Range("Cr4").Value
        WS.Range("d19").Value = "=IFS($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Brand],"""",0),"""",)"
        WS.Range("d20").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Supplier],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d21").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[No. Other Suppliers],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d24").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Pack],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d25").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Cost],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d26").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Variance],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d27").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Variance %],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d30").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Buy Box ],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d31").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Target Sales Price],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d32").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Price Performance],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d34").Value = "=d31"
        WS.Range("d35").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Max Cost],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d36").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Profit],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d37").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[ROI),"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d42").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Total Sales],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d43").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Competitive Low Price],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d44").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Competitive High Price],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d45").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Competitive Sellers],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d46").Value = "=IF($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Supplier],"""",0),"""")"
        WS.Range("d49").Value = "=IFNA(IFS(D40=""Pass"",""Yes"",D40=""Fail"",""No""),"""")"
        WS.Range("d50").Value = "=IFNA(IFS(D41=""No Known Issues"",""Yes""),"""")"
        WS.Range("d51").Value = "IFNA(IFS(AND(ProfitCalc=""ROI"",D37>=CP_TargetROI),""Yes"",AND(ProfitCalc=""Profit"",D37>=CP_TargetProfit),""Yes""),""No"")"
        WS.Range("d52").Value = "=IF(AND(D46<>"""",D46<CP_SalesTarget),""No"",""Yes"")"""")"
        
        Debug.Print WSfrom.Range("Cr4").Value
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you step through with F8? Also, it'd be best to specify the workbook before `Sheets("Validation Form")` and `Sheets("DATA - Product Validation")`, and it seems better to me to use `.Formula2` instead of `.Value`, if you're writing a formula.

Comment: It looks like your `WS.Range("d19").Value = "=IFS($D$18<>"""",XLOOKUP($D$18,ProductTable[ASIN],ProductTable[Brand],"""",0),"""",)"` should be just an `IF` statement. If that is the case, I would remove the last `,` before the second `)`

Comment: thanks for spotting that.... It seems to be the 3rd set statement as when I run it and comment it out it works...

Comment: got it I had selected the wring sheet...I thougtht it would have thrown an error out on that!  thanks for the other suggestions to

Comment: I'd change the sheet references to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Validation Form")` indicating the workbook the code is in, otherwise it will use the currently active workbook.  Also no need for `Set Tbl = WSfrom.ListObjects("ProductTable")` as you don't use it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had selected the wrong sheet... I thought it would have thrown an error when I tried to set TBL to the table name...